# Android Marshmallow view user certificates and associate cert with private key

Tags: android, security, certificate, android-6.0-marshmallow, keystore

1. I've created a key pair, stored the private key in the AndroidKeystore.
2. Generated a CSR using the Public key from the key pair
3. Exported the CSR to the CA, and got it to generate a cert
4. Installed the cert on the phone

Now, I'm trying to associate the private key from #1 with the cert that was installed at step #4.

Have looked all day, cannot find a mechanism to do it. Android documentation suggests using the KeyStore.setKeyEntry method. I intend to use it but am unable to read the cert that was installed.

I can display all certs in the AndroidCAStore, and I do see this newly installed cert in the "User certificates" section on the phone but am unable to read it programatically. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do pretty much the same thing. The key association with the signed cert also works using keystore.setEntry. What I can't get to work is this user cert then to appear in the "IPSec User certificate" listbox when trying to add a VPN. Running on Marshmallow 6.0.1

My logic looks like this
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");

```
        keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "AndroidKeyStore");

        keyGen.initialize(
                new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                        "myAlias",
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                        .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp384r1"))
                        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
                                KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA384,
                                KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                        .setKeyValidityStart(now)
                        .setKeyValidityForOriginationEnd(nowPlusThreeYears)
                        .build());

  keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
  privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("myAlias", null);
  publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate("myAlias").getPublicKey();

  Certificate[] chain = keyStore.getCertificateChain("myAlias");
  keyStore.setKeyEntry("myAlias", privateKey, null, chain);

  StringBuilder x500PrincipalBuilder = new StringBuilder("CN=");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append("My Company");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append(", ");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append("L=");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append("My Location");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append(", ");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append("ST=");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append("CA");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append(", ");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append("O=");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append("My Org");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append(", ");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append("OU=");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append("my ou");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append(", ");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append("C=");
    x500PrincipalBuilder.append("US");

  Signature ecdsaSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA384withECDSA");
  ecdsaSignature.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate());

  byte[] strByte = new byte[0];
  strByte = x500PrincipalBuilder.toString().getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);
  ecdsaSignature.update(strByte);


    X500Principal x500Principal = new X500Principal(x500PrincipalBuilder.toString());
    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder p10Builder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
            x500Principal, keyPair.getPublic());

    JcaContentSignerBuilder csBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(signatureGenerator.getSigningAlgorithm());
    ContentSigner signer = csBuilder.build(keyPair.getPrivate());

    org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = p10Builder.build(signer);

    PemObject pemObject = new PemObject("CERTIFICATE REQUEST", csr.getEncoded());
    StringWriter str = new StringWriter();
    PEMWriter pemWriter = new PEMWriter(str);
    pemWriter.writeObject(pemObject);
    pemWriter.close();
    str.close();


// write the csr to a file
// get it signed by the CA (Microsoft CA)
// Push the cert to the phone
// Install the cert

Certificate clientCertSignedByCA = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("/path/to/cert.cer));
    KeyStore.Entry entry = keyStore.getEntry("myAlias", null);
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("myAlias", null);
Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[1];
chain[0] = clientCertSignedByCA;
keyStore.setKeyEntry("myAlias", privateKey, null, chain);
```